# How to register Trasport Listener with Javax.mail.Transport to hear back email sent status from email server

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to capture email status from email server, For that I have configured TransportListener . But the TransportListener event not triggered after sending email using Transport.send() . I came to know Transport.send() will create new instance but we need to register Transport instance with TransportListener. I did not find the way how to register Transport instance with TransportListener to trigger the methods messageDelivered(), messageNotDelivered() of TransportListener.

Can any one please suggest how I can register my Transport with TransportListener to know the status of my emails from email server.

==Below code snippet to capture delivery status code from mail server====

```
SMTPTransport transport = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtp");





        transport.connect("host","Port","Username","password");

        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        //transport.simpleCommand(cmd);
        String response = transport.getLastServerResponse();
        boolean s = transport.getReportSuccess();
        int code = transport.getLastReturnCode();
        System.out.println("response is:" + response);
        System.out.println("report is:" + s);
        System.out.println("Code is:" + code);
        transport.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that TransportListener will only tell you if your mail server rejects your message, which is that same information you get from an except from Transport.send.
If you want to know whether the message was ultimately delivered to the recipient, you need to learn about Delivery Status Notifications, but see [this JavaMail FAQ entry](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#badaddr).

Comment: Thanks Bill for your response.  Please see the above code snippet (added to my main thread above) which I used to capture delivery status codes from mail server by using SMTPTransport. But even I used bogus email id (abc@xyz.com) I have received 250 code instead of  getting 550. Can you help me why I got wrong delivery status code , am I missing anything?

Comment: Read the FAQ entry again.  The server isn't going to validate the email address for anything other than maybe syntax before accepting it.  And there's nothing wrong with the address abc@xyz.com.

Comment: true, But once It reaches mail server mail server identifies that address is invalid and It will give response code 550 with description to my inbox, Is there any way may code to get that response code 550 after server identified the address as invalid?  And the FAQ the  links are not working , appreciate if you provide me latest links.

Comment: The server may queue the message for processing after it drops the connection with the client, so at the time it discovers there's a problem, the client is gone.  It might send a "mailer-daemon" message back to the client indicating the failure, but that's not required.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For the question --" Q: When a message can't be delivered, a failure message is returned. How can I detect these "bounced" messages?" the links giving 404 page not found.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed these in the [new version of the FAQ in the Eclipse project](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/FAQ).

Answer (score 0):

You can add transport listener to get back the status

```
        transport.addTransportListener(new TransportListener() {
        @Override
        public void messagePartiallyDelivered(TransportEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        
        @Override
        public void messageNotDelivered(TransportEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        
        @Override
        public void messageDelivered(TransportEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
     transport.connect(smtpServer, port, userid, password);
```